# Count of One Column by Another

Tags: r

Lets say that I have the following data frame with a user id and location as the two columns. A user id can have multiple locations. I'm interested in finding the could of each possible location sequence based on the user id.

So if my data looked like this:

```
places = data.frame(user_id=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                  location=c("home","school","work","home","school","work",
                             "lunch","airport","gym","breakfast","work","home"))
places
```

I want to find the following:

```
freq = data.frame(location_path=c("home - school", "work", "home - school - work", 
                                  "lunch - airport", "gym - breakfast - work - home"),
                  count=c(1,1,1,1,1))
freq
```

This second data frame tells me that the 'home' and 'school' pairing occurred twice in that order. Furthermore, the home, school, and work pairing occurred only once as well.

Of course there could be instances where the pairing occurs multiple times. In the following case the home, school, and work pairing would have a count of 2.

```
   places = data.frame(user_id=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                      location=c("home","school","work","home","school","work",
                                 "lunch","airport","gym","breakfast","work","home",
                                 "home","school","work"))
places
```

Comment: "home - school" in `freq` should be 2? (because you mention that "it occurs twice in that order"). Or a combination of locations shouldn't be taken account of if it exists in another combination?

Comment: Also, see if you make use of `as.data.frame(table(aggregate(location ~ user_id, places, paste, collapse = " - ")$location))`

Comment: For that, "it occurs twice in that order" because the pairing consists of only two locations. So if that combination (home-school) is in another grouping (home-school-work), it shouldn't count that